# Using std::istream_iterator to read binary data from file stops prematuraly

Tags: c++

I am trying to read binary data from file using the following code:

```
std::ifstream fp;
fp.open("C:\\my_binary_data.dat", std::ios::binary);
std::istream_iterator<byte> start(fp), end;
std::vector<byte> tof(start, end);
fp.close();
```

The file has 401 bytes, but the tof vector is only 380 elements long, i.e. it stops reading before the end. The `end` is set to nullptr(?), thus the iterator reads until it reads a zero byte? The 380th byte is 109. What is the stop condition here? And how can I be sure it reads the whole file?

Using

```
fp.seekg (0, fp.end);
std::streamoff length = fp.tellg();
fp.seekg (1, fp.beg);
```

gives length=401

Comment: According to [the manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) `std::istream_iterator` skips whitespace before reading. You maybe want [std::istreambuf_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator)?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but instead of creating a default-constructed file object then opening it, just open it when it's created: `std::ifstream fp("C:\\my_binary_data.dat", std::ios::binary);`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, so it behaves differently if you use default constructor, then open, than openconstructor? Isnt that rather confusing. Is this documented?

Comment: @PeteBecker, that gave the same behaviour, luckily.

Comment: @thorsan - it wasn't luck. That's how it works. <g> In general, instead of creating something and then assigning to it, initialize it with the value that it would get from the assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`istream_iterator` is an avatar of `operator >>`; it uses that operator to read from the stream. That is almost never what you want for reading binary data, because `>>` is a *formatted* input function. You could probably coerce it to do what you want by using manipulators such as `noskipws` on the stream, but it would still effectively remain a use of the wrong tool for the job.

If you want an iterator-based access to binary data in a stream, you might be better off using an `istreambuf_iterator` (which is guaranteed to work character by character) instead.